# Correct way to include bootstrap.css.map?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, angular-ui-bootstrap

Is this the correct way to include bootstrap.css.map?

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css.map" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to load it just delete the line `/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.css.map */` from `bootstrap.css`

Comment: Its already deleted in bootstrap.css.we didn't include it anywhere and deleted from bootstrap.css, so whats the use of bootstrap.css?

Comment: what is your objective here? are you seeing an error? are you using sass?

Comment: I am creating an App in angularjs. But my view page seems like error..style is not working properly.so I thought Its because of bootstrap.css.map

Comment: You just need to load bootstrap.css not bootstrap.css.map

Comment: Just make sure that you are pointing to the right bootstrap.css path. If your bootstrap.css is inside your css folder and the css folder is at the root level beside the index.html then yes your path should be css/bootstrap.css

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the actual map files from Bootstrap, probably better to install ng-bootstrap. Fits more to Angular.

`npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

import in your main module.